# Are there some smarter smart pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, reference-counting

Quite often I work with an old code where raw pointers are mixed with smart ones and I don't have the time to change all raw ones to smart.

And there can be some situations like static raw pointer pointing to an object, which can be already destructed and at first it seems like a situation to use weak_ptr to hold the reference, but there the problem arises, because the place with raw pointer does not have any information about shared_ptrs already pointing to the same object.

So:
1) Is there any smarter smart pointer that tracks all pointers (both raw and smart) to an object?
2) Is there any smarter smart pointer that at least tracks all shared_ptrs to an object?

I don't want a discussion about an implementation, if possible I want to use it as a black-box.

EDIT: I asked 2), because for example calling make_shared on an object twice, makes 2 separate shared_ptr reference counters.

Comment: Short answers: no and no.

Comment: Just think for a second: How would you implement such a smarter smart pointer? How do you catch it when a member function returns a pointer/reference to one of its members? How do you catch it when a member function returns `this`? If you answer like me "that's impossible to do", well, you got the reason why no such things exists...

Comment: (1) is surely impossible. Can you elaborate on (2)? Do you want to get a list of all `shared_ptr`s to an object given... a raw pointer to it? Or a shared one?

Comment: Concerning #2: `std::shared_ptr<>` already does this. It has to. That's why you must not create two different `std::shared_ptr<>` to the same object from raw pointers. You must create one `std::shared_ptr<>` from a raw pointer, and then derive all the other `std::shared_ptr<>` from that first one, directly or indirectly. Otherwise, your shared pointers don't know about each other, and double free your object (and do so prematurely at that).

Comment: I don't think there is an easy fix. You would have to track the usage of each pointer and convert (or not convert) on a case by case basis. Not all pointers should be smart pointers btw.

Comment: Sounds like you want objects to be self-aware that they are managed by a smart pointer (i.e., a `std::shared_ptr`).  That's what [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) does.  Note that some people (myself included) consider this an anti-pattern, but it is part-and-parcel of the C++ language by the standard.

Comment: Some issues you mentioned can be solved by intrusive reference counting strategy. See [intrusive_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr). In any case, smart pointer is a paradigm  - this paradigm not giving you different programming language with garbage collection, anyway it is safer then raw C pointers.

Comment: @Eljay That can in fact work, but first I didn't understand the purpose of the example. So I understand it that I create first shared_ptr using make_shared and then every time I create another shared_ptr, it counts all shared_ptr to the same object together. It solves 2) and is better than nothing :)

Comment: Note that if you have `Foo foo;` and then do `auto ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>(foo);` you have a pointer to a *copy* of `foo`, i.e. a separate object

Comment: @Caleth So is there a syntax or mechanism different than std::enable_shared_from_this that allows you to make 2 shared_ptr using make_shared to use 1 reference counter?

Comment: No. `make_shared<Foo>` allocates and constructs a new `Foo`. To have two shared pointers sharing ownership of one object, have one be a copy of the other. I.e. `auto ptr1 = std::make_shared<Foo>(foo_args...); auto ptr2 = ptr1;`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, thanks and that's the problem, because I don't always have that original ptr1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is there any smarter smart pointer that tracks all pointers (both raw and smart) to an object?

No. There is no such standard pointer and such pointer is not implementable in standard C++.

> 2) Is there any smarter smart pointer that at least tracks all shared_ptrs to an object?

It is somewhat unclear what you mean. Ownership is implicitly shared with all copies of the shared pointer. If you mean that you want taking ownership with separate shared pointers to work, there is no such smart pointer in C++. Maybe implementable with a global data structure.

On the other hand, `std::enable_shared_from_this` *might* be what you're looking for instead. It still doesn't work if you try to take shared ownership separately, but it provides a convenient way to join an existing ownership without needing access to any of the shared pointers.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning std::enable_shared_from_this, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this. It may solve some use cases similar to the one in the question.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Added mention.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to program in a language not based in any way shape or form on C.

C has pointers. Smart pointers are not real pointers.

Unless you invent a different language, not compatible at any level with C, you will always have pointers and these won't be under the control of any so called "smart pointer", which is neither smart nor a pointer.

Comment: @LukasSalich Indeed GC is hugely problematic. Did you know that historically Java (not modern, saner Java) allowed collection of objects that were currently in use? It's very difficult to specify any reliable user cleanup with a GC.

Comment: I know, I used Java in college that time :)